# d3 connected scatterplot example, question on syntax

Tags: javascript, d3.js, observablehq

In this example: https://observablehq.com/@d3/connected-scatterplot

The first block of code begins like this:

```
chart = {
  replay;

//...create svg element and setup the chart...

  return svg.node();
}
```

Two questions (I apologize if these are simple but I'm new to javascript and google is not availing me anything):

1) chart looks like a function since it has a return statement, but there is no function keyword. If I try something like this for myself in my flask application, I get errors when I put a return statement because it is being evaluated as an object definition? Is this some node.js thing?

2) What is that line "replay;" doing? I don't see any references to it elsewhere in the code

Edit: I found the answer here: https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/observables-not-javascript

In short, anything on that website is not-quite-javascript, which is really confusing when learning D3.js and almost all the examples are on that website (and the above page is somewhat difficult to find). But I guess that's all part of the business model to get people to subscribe and develop on observablehq rather than writing standalone web apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I work for Observable, and yeah, “[Observable’s not JavaScript](http://%20https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/observables-not-javascript)” is the best thing to read on that. `chart` is declaring a reactive variable; it uses no keyword; it can be defined as a single expression, like `x = d3.scaleLinear()`, or as a curly-braces function block that returns a value, as you saw. You can download the notebook compiled into plain JavaScript by clicking “Download code” in the “⋯” menu in the upper right; here I’ve [annotated the source](http://www.tophtucker.com/observable-docco/index.js.html) of a line chart example. You can see there how the cell gets compiled into a normal JavaScript function that’s passed the values of the other cells it depends on. In that “Connected Scatterplot” example, if you download the code, the body of the `chart` cell ends up looking like this:

```js
function(replay, d3, width, height, length, line, data, xAxis, yAxis, x, y, halo) {
  replay;
    
  //...create svg element and setup the chart...
      
  return svg.node();
}
```

The way reactivity works is that each cell is re-evaluated whenever one of the cells it refers to changes. The `replay;` line takes advantage of that to redraw the scatterplot when you click the button, which fires its click event, which triggers the reactive re-evaluation, even though it’s not passing any data or being assigned to a variable or anything.

(I suppose it is a business, but we’re really trying to make coding these things easier! Happy to chat if you have questions.)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was definitely being a bit salty complaining because I had spent so much time googling without coming across the first page you linked. I will definitely come back to your annotated code next time I'm working with observable code.